# How to reorder a list in Python based on its content

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a list of dictionaries in python like this;

```
l = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 23},
     {'name': 'Steve', 'age': 35},
     {'name': 'Helen'},
     {'name': 'George'},
     {'name': 'Jessica', 'age': 23}]
```

What I am trying to achieve here is reorder the elements of `l` in such a way that each entry containing the key `age` move to the end of the list like this;

End result:

```
l = [{'name': 'Helen'},
     {'name': 'George'},
     {'name': 'Jessica', 'age': 23},
     {'name': 'John', 'age': 23},
     {'name': 'Steve', 'age': 35}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If the dict has an age, do you also want it sorted by the age?

Comment: Your sample output is *also* sorted by age. Was that intentional?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No it wasn't. Pure randomness here. I am currently not interested at age ordering therefore your answer below is more than enough. Thank you.

Comment: @Konos5: you may want to adjust that order then and make it explicit. You got both options from me in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the list:

```
l.sort(key=lambda d: 'age' in d)
```

The key returns either `True` or `False`, based on the presence of the `'age'` key; `True` is sorted after `False`. Python's sort is stable, leaving the rest of the relative ordering intact.

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> l = [{'name': 'John', 'age': 23},
...      {'name': 'Steve', 'age': 35},
...      {'name': 'Helen'},
...      {'name': 'George'},
...      {'name': 'Jessica', 'age': 23}]
>>> l.sort(key=lambda d: 'age' in d)
>>> pprint(l)
[{'name': 'Helen'},
 {'name': 'George'},
 {'age': 23, 'name': 'John'},
 {'age': 35, 'name': 'Steve'},
 {'age': 23, 'name': 'Jessica'}]
```

If you *also* wanted to sort by age, then retrieve the age value and return a suitable stable sentinel for those entries that do not have an age, but which will be sorted first. `float('-inf')` will always be sorted before any other number, for example:

```
l.sort(key=lambda d: d.get('age', float('-inf')))
```

Again, entries without an age are left in their original relative order:

```
>>> l.sort(key=lambda d: d.get('age', float('-inf')))
>>> pprint(l)
[{'name': 'Helen'},
 {'name': 'George'},
 {'age': 23, 'name': 'John'},
 {'age': 23, 'name': 'Jessica'},
 {'age': 35, 'name': 'Steve'}]
```

Comment: suggest to use `l.sort(key=lambda d: d.get('age', -1))`, as it will also sort by the ages

Comment: @stalk: I'm not yet sure if that was the intention, but I'll expand.